# Regex to search in an array of strings

Tags: java, arrays

Consider the following strings in an array defined in Java

```
G1
G12
G1-G2
G23
```

- If the user enters `G1`, then the program should return the index of `G1` and `G1-G2` - > `[0, 2]`
- If the user enters `G2`, the program should return the index `G1-G2` -> `[2]`
- If the user enters `G12`, the program should return the index of `G12` -> `[1]`
- ...

One easy way to do that is to tokenize each array element with `'-'` and then use `equals()` for each element. That means an O(n^2) algorithm. Is there a better way to use regular expressions so that in one loop, the program searches for the pattern and use `'-'` as delimiting character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution would be to use the following regex;

```
.*(?=\b{value}\b).*
```

so, for example if you wish to capture `G1` with your requirements;

```
.*(?=\bG1\b).*
```

Where `\b` is being utilized, the anchor for the beginning or the end of a word, that is perfect for your requirement. More on word boundary anchor `\b`, [here](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=regex%20%5Cb&oq=regex%20%5Cb&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2256j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

in Java I have the following code to test;

```
static List<String> list = Arrays.asList("G1", "G12", "G1-G2", "G23");
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("G1", "G12", "G2", "G23")).forEach(s -> func(s));
}

static void func(String input) {
    String regex = ".*(?=\\b" + input + "\\b).*";
    System.out.println(input + " contained in -> " 
                       + Arrays.toString(IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                                       .filter(i -> list.get(i).matches(regex))
                                       .toArray()));
}
```

which results in;

```
G1 contained in -> [0, 2]
G12 contained in -> [1]
G2 contained in -> [2]
G23 contained in -> [3]
```

To see the code in action, [here](http://rextester.com/JVWPW92219)